# how to reference an image in a dokument

Tags: xpages

I have an image that is stored within a document in the database.
the following url will open the image from the web client in the image control

/file/winter/$file/winter.jpg

but it doesn't work from the notes client.
How should I change the url to get it to work in the Notes client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image is actually an attachment. You need the /xsp approach:

```
 http(s)://[yourserver]/[application.nsf] /xsp/.ibmmodres/domino/OpenAttachment/ [application.nsf]/[UNID|/$File/[AttachmentName]?Open
```

Check the [full details](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-86QKNM). Most likely you can  skip the server and application part

Comment: it seams like the notes client want the url like this
/xsp/.ibmmodres/domino/OpenAttachment/[server]!! [application.nsf]/[UNID|/$File/[AttachmentName]?Open
Thanks for the help